# Excluding a specific directory using Maven jar-with-dependencies

Tags: maven, jar

I'm using `jar-with-dependencies` in Maven to create a compiled jar file for my project. However, one of the dependencies has got source code in its jar in a non-standard place (`/jvm/`), and this is being included in the combined output jar.

How do I exclude a specific directory in a specific jar from being included in the combined output jar? An `<excludes>` tag doesn't seem to be valid anywhere in the plugin definition (at least, IntelliJ doesn't think it's valid)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have never used `jar-with-dependencies` but for the same problem you mentioned above we used [maven-shade-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/shade-mojo.html) in our project to include and exclude classes from particular packages.

```
 <excludes>
      <exclude>com.techidiocy.dump.*</exclude>
 </excludes>
```

In above it will ignore all the classes from the package `com.techidiocy.dump`

Thanks